Embedding a HTML table in R Markdown
I need your help with my R Markdown file, let me first show you a screenshot:
Embedded HTML Table
As you can see there are two identical table, the first is displayed using the image link:
![]("activity_tableSQL.html")
The second one is displayed using the function:
htmltools::includeHTML("activity_tableSQL.html")
I want to embed a html table into my .rmd file instead of displaying it as an image link, but when I use the second function, the table overlaps and displays all 100 records (see screenshot). So how can I embed the table and make sure it fits the screen-width like the image link above?

Do you have access to the dataset? If yes, why not write the table directly into you markdown document using any library of your choice instead of trying to embed a HTML document?

@IfeanyiIdiaye yes I do have access to the dataset. The thing is I used MySQL Workbench to clean the dataset then I exported it from SQL as html in order to import it to R Markdown

Can you export it from SQL as an external .csv file?

@IfeanyiIdiaye Yes I can, but there's like 10 other html documents like this one that I need to change so exporting them as .csv  will take too much time. Isn't there any other solution besides that?

You could use rvest::read_html() and rvest::html_table() to read the html tables as a dataset.
Because we do not have one of your html export files, I am not sure of their structure, but here is an example using a Workbench export from my end and printing the data with gt::gt():
library(gt)
library(rvest)

"activity_tableSQL.html" |>
  read_html() |>
  html_table(header = TRUE) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  gt()

Created on 2024-08-23 with reprex v2.1.1

@the-mad-satter Thank you for your response, I haven't tried your way but I did end up figuring it out. Rather than making changes in R, I went to HTML and made changes there. This is the code I used: <div style="overflow-x: auto">table content</div>
